# How to bypass a connection from going through a VPN?

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, vpn

Network setup looks like the following:

```
Internet --> Router1 doing PPPOE and VPN --> Switch --> Router2 + other stuff
```

Router 1 is running Linux with iptables, connects to my ISP and after a successful connection to a VPN. However, Router2 should not go through the VPN while everything else connected to Router1 should.

How to bypass a connection from going through a VPN?
I also don't know if the switch matters in this scenario.

Comment: Presumably router2 is doing SNAT on traffic originating from behind it, to its IP address in the LAN range of router1?

Comment: what do you mean by router2 should not go through VPN ? Also providing some (even fake) IP and route table would be lovely so we have a bit more context.

Comment: @wurtel : yes  Everything on router1 will go through the VPN by default. Hence, all devices connected to router2 which again is connected to router1 would go through the VPN. But I don't want connections from devices connected to router2 to go through the VPN and I guess the only or likely easiest option would be to somehow bypass the VPN for everything coming from router2. I'll try to add some ip's and routing table but this might take a while. I guess it should be doable somehow with the prerouting table or adding another route for router2.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is policy based routing. See `man ip-rule`

Set up a rule to match router2

```
ip rule add from router2 table 200
```

Set up a route for that rule that points to the correct gateway. `$GATEWAY` should be the default gateway or router1 before VPN is started.

```
ip route add default via $GATEWAY table 200
```